# How can I sort the children of option_groups_from_collection_for_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a select list with optgroups and child options rendered from `option_groups_from_collection_for_select`

This works fine but I don't see any way to specify the sort order of each child section in any documentation.  I'd prefer not to have to resort to mapping and sorting myself; I would think this would be a common enough need to be part of the helper.

How can I sort the children in each grouping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare an order in your `has_many`.  Taking the example in the api doc http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select you could do this:

```
class Continent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :countries, -> { order("countries.name") }
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :continent
end
```

If you want specialized data in a collection_select it's usually easiest to handle it in the model.

Comment: I'd discourage default ordering because you will need to `reorder` if you need something else.

Comment: @schmijos Normally I would, too, but when using `option_groups_from_collection_for_select` there's no other way to get the order.